# How to see permissions in cleartool

Tags: clearcase

I tried ls command, but it doesn't actually show permissions for VOB elements. I cannot understand what command to use in order to see the permissions. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can use [`cleartool describe`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-9):

```
 cleartool descr -l yourFile

 # for the vob itself:
 cleartool descr -l vob:\vobtag
```

The second command is important, as it would list the primary and secondary groups associated to the vob: you must have your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` set to one of those groups in order to access the vob.

Using [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6), you also have access to the filesystem object permission:

```
%[permissions]p
```

> File system objects: Displays the object's permissions using the standard "`rwx`" notation.

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%[permissions]p" .
```